# insertRows in TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I get data through JSON and when I scroll the screen I have a request to the server and sometimes the data can end and then the application crashes on `insertRows` how can I fix it?

here my code:

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (!isMoreDataLoading) {

        let down = "https://--.com/local/apps/apple/events.php/?nPageSize=\(nPageSize)&iNumPage=\(iNumPage)"
        let scrollViewContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
        let scrollOffsetThreshold = scrollViewContentHeight - tableView.bounds.size.height
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollOffsetThreshold && tableView.isDragging) {
            isMoreDataLoading = true
            requestD(url: down) 
        }
    }
}
func requestD(url:String){

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 300
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error ?? 0)
            return
        }
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let newsJson = json["EVENTS"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                for newJson in newsJson{
                    let info = Modal()

                    info.id = newJson["ID"] as? String
                    info.name = newJson["NAME"] as? String

                    if newJson["PICTURE"] as? String != nil {
                        info.ImageViewURL = newJson["PICTURE"] as! String
                    }
                    if newJson["PICTURE_DETAIL"] as? String != nil {
                        info.ImageViewURLDetail = newJson["PICTURE_DETAIL"] as! String
                    }
                    info.stmp = newJson["STMP"] as? Int
                    info.text = newJson["DETAIL_TEXT"] as? String


                    info.name = info.name?.replacingOccurrences(of: "&[^;]+;", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
                    info.text = info.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "&[^;]+;", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)


                    if self.isRefresh == true {
                        self.modals.insert(info, at: 0)
                    } else {
                        self.modals.append(info)
                    }



                }
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {

            self.iNumPage += 1
            self.isMoreDataLoading = false


            self.Preload.preloadEnd(tableView: self.tableView)

           // self.tableView.reloadData()


            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.modals.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

reason: `'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting new table row you are not adding new data in array.
Add this code `self.modals.insert("<#DATA#>, atIndex: yourIndex)` before inserting new row in table. And try to remove DispatchQueue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150771/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-vasya2014).

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing/ inserting an element in the tableView you would need to do the following:

1. Add the data in the backing datasource of the tableView.
2. Reload the tableView.

Some code to illustrate the point (this code was placed in didSelectRowAtIndexPath):

```
 anArray.insert("This String", atIndex: indexPath.row)
 tableView.reloadData()
```